# SQL Server : insert parameter null, but has value in C#

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

When I run this code, I get this exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MultipleAnswerNameID', table 'G2A.dbo.MultipleAnswerName'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

MultiAnswerNameID has a value, even when I debug...

The exception is thrown when the program comes to this code:

```
rows += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My code:

```
SqlCommand command = null;
int rows = 0;

using (SqlConnection connection = G2ADB.GetConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    int answerID = addAnswer((int)G2A.Type.MultipleAnswer, transaction, connection);

    try
    {
        SqlParameter prmanswerID = new SqlParameter("@answerid", answerID);

        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT MultipleAnswer (AnswerID) VALUES (@answerid)", connection, transaction);
        command.Parameters.Add(prmanswerID);

        rows += command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows == 1)
        {
           DebugMess.debugMessage("Added answer");
        }

        rows = 0;
        DebugMess.debugMessage(answerID.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < answers.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT MultipleAnswerName (MultipleAnswerName, MultipleAnswerCorrect,MultipleAnswerID) VALUES (@answerName,@answerCor,@multianswerid)";

            SqlParameter prmopenanswerid = new SqlParameter("@multianswerid", answerID);
            SqlParameter prmanswerName = new SqlParameter("@answerName", answers[i, 0]);
            SqlParameter prmanswerVariable = new SqlParameter("@answerCor", answers[i, 1]);

            command.Parameters.Add(prmopenanswerid);
            command.Parameters.Add(prmanswerName);
            command.Parameters.Add(prmanswerVariable);

            rows += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

         if (rows == answers.GetLength(0))
         {
            transaction.Commit();
            DebugMess.debugMessage("Transaction of the answer committed.");
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          transaction.Rollback();
          DebugMess.debugMessage("Transaction of the answer failed.\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
          connection.Close();
      }
      return answerID;
```

Comment: does MultiAnswerNameID is your primarykey in MultipleAnswerName table?

Comment: i think you just miss to put MultiAnswerNameID in your insert statement or if this field is autonumber maybe you forget to set you field identity specification to yes

Answer (score 0):

Check your insert statement.you are missing `into`

```
INSERT into  MultipleAnswer (AnswerID) VALUES (@answerid)
```

---

```
INSERT into MultipleAnswerName (MultipleAnswerName, MultipleAnswerCorrect,MultipleAnswerID) VALUES 
(@answerName,@answerCor,@multianswerid);
```

Comment: I've tried it. It still gives the same error..
Thx anyway!

Comment: @RafVandelaer May I know why are you using rows += command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: That's to check how many rows are updated/altered.
It works on other sql commands, it's just this one that does something weird

Answer (score 0):

Change This line

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT MultipleAnswerName (MultipleAnswerName, MultipleAnswerCorrect,MultipleAnswerID) VALUES (@answerName,@answerCor,@multianswerid)";
command = new SqlCommand("INSERT MultipleAnswer (AnswerID) VALUES (@answerid)", connection, transaction);
```

With

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MultipleAnswerName (MultipleAnswerName, MultipleAnswerCorrect,MultipleAnswerID) VALUES (@answerName,@answerCor,@multianswerid)";
command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MultipleAnswer (AnswerID) VALUES (@answerid)", connection, transaction);
```

**EDIT**

Change the parameter Order

```
 for (int i = 0; i < answers.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
   command.Parameters.Clear();
   command.CommandText = "INSERT Into MultipleAnswerName (MultipleAnswerName, MultipleAnswerCorrect,MultipleAnswerID) VALUES (@answerName,@answerCor,@multianswerid)";
   SqlParameter prmanswerName = new SqlParameter("@answerName", answers[i, 0]);
   SqlParameter prmanswerVariable = new SqlParameter("@answerCor", answers[i, 1]);
   SqlParameter prmopenanswerid = new SqlParameter("@multianswerid", answerID);

   command.Parameters.Add(prmanswerName);
   command.Parameters.Add(prmanswerVariable);
   command.Parameters.Add(prmopenanswerid);
   rows += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the same exception:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MultipleAnswerNameID', table 'G2A.dbo.MultipleAnswerName'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Can you put break point in for loop and make sure that you are getting values

Comment: @RafVandelaer I have updated solution. Can you check with that

Comment: Tried it.. same error.. But thanks for helping me out..

Here some screens
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34606846/exception.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34606846/values.png

Comment: Check this line that have ID values command.Parameters.Add(prmopenanswerid);

Comment: Problem solved!

The dude who created the DB had forgotten to set autonumbering on.. --'

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.